# How to check if my unique jwplayer for a video exist

Tags: html5-video, jwplayer, video-player, jwplayer6

I need to check if my jwplayer exist, For example, if i have two videos in page `video1` and `video2`.

How do I check `jwplayer("video1").exist() or jwplayer("video2").exist()`

I want to remove the unique jwplayer player only if the unique jwplayer exist to avoid unnecessary error such as

```
uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function
```

I have tried onReady() but I think it is only executed once at intial state of player

> **onReady(callback)** - Fired when the player has initialized in either
>   Flash or HTML5 and is ready for playback. Has no attributes.

I have even tried this trick below but it did not work

```
 //checking if jwplayer media div exist
    var jw_mode = jwplayer('mediaId').getRenderingMode();
    if(jQuery('#'+mediaId).length){
       if( (jw_mode == 'html5') || (jw_mode == 'flash')) {
                alert("it works")
               //remove jwplayer from DOM
                 jwplayer(mediaId).remove();
       } 
    }
```

Above throws Error `uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function` 
if I use the wrong Id by mistake `jwplayer("id")`

so to avoid this problem I need to remove the player only if uniqueJwPlayer exist on close button instead of hiding it.

```
If (myUniqueJwPlayer.exist){
   jwplayer(myUniqueJwPlayer).remove()
}
```

How to do this in using Jwplayer

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/nLr7k/25/

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer - 
http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/nLr7k/25/
Click on `show player` then quickly click on `remove player` when buffer is still loading. even player is removed you can hear the audio in background

Comment: It seems to remove fine for me and the audio goes away. What browser are you using? I was using FF 29.

Comment: Hm, I checked Chrome on Win7, it seeks ok?